# Keep one value of a duplicate

Tags: pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe with possible duplicate values and would like to keep rows that have the value yes in the ans column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10],
'ans': ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(n = 8)
```

The expected output should be

```
data2 = {
'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'ans': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.head(n = 10)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: Does the `ans`col act as identifier for duplicates? If yes you could simple use `df.drop_duplicates(["id"],keep="last")`

Comment: OK, so my answer is what need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need filter `yes` values by mask with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for prioritize `yes` if exist per groups, last select matched rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df['ans'].eq('yes').groupby(df['id']).idxmax()]
print (df)
    id  ans
1    1  yes
2    2  yes
3    3   no
4    4   no
5    5  yes
7    6  yes
8    7   no
10   8  yes
12   9  yes
13  10   no
```

Comment: Isn't this a little complicated? A simple `query`or `loc` filter should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either

```py
df.query("ans=='yes'")
```

or

```py
df.loc[df.ans == 'yes',:]
```

Comment: If there are duplicate "yes" answers, maybe OP would like to drop them: `df.query("ans == 'yes'").drop_duplicates("id")`

Comment: If he wants to, that's correct. However as I understand the question it's a simple filter on all `yes`columns.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on the expected output